# Kafka Connect manual offset/commit management

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to handle the offset commits myself in a custom Kafka connect connector I'm working on.

I have tried configuring in the connector config this - "consumer.enable.auto.commit": "false".

In addition, I overrided the preCommit method in the class that inherits from the SinkTask class so it returns an empty map since according to the docs, that is required in order to manage the offset manually (reference https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/sink/SinkTask.html#preCommit-java.util.Map-).

I have also tried calling the flush method with an empty map.

However, with all of the above and permutations of these attempts, the messages were still committed and were not reprocessed (just to be clear, my goal is that if the message was not committed, it will be consumed again in the next poll interval).

What else can I do in order to make the consumed message not be committed and consumed again in the next poll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was my lack of understanding of how Kafka works.
Basically the offset progress is being tracked in memory and the flush/preCommit is just for taking what's in memory and write to disk.

That means flushing an older offset will be taken *only* the next time the consumer will be restarted (as it reads the offset it needs to start from, from disk).

There is another method inside the SinkTaskContext called "offset" that takes a map of topic partition and offset and setting it in memory for the consumer.

The KafkaConnect runtime, before each poll, is taking the tracked offset in memory and if needed, calls the underline consumer seek method according to the map stored by the offset method mentioned before.

This, in turn, will actually make the consumer to read the offset as it was set in the "offset" method.